# How to create post in WP network using WP-CLI

Tags: posts, multisite, wp-cli

How create post using *WP-CLI* at time of network site create. I am creating network sites using *WP-CLI*.
I have tried:

```
wp post create --post_type=page --post_title='ABC' --post_status=publish --network
```

But it creates post on main site. But, I want to create that post on network site which was created that time.

Thanks in advance.
Any reference will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the `--url` argument to target a given **site** in your network:

```
wp post create \
   --post_type=page \ 
   --post_title='ABC' \
   --post_status=publish \
   --url=http://example.tld/somesite/
```

where you can view available site urls with

```
wp site list
```

Answer (score 1):

Global attribute `--url=<url>` is required to post in a networked site.

wp post create `--url=subdomain.exampledomain.com [OPTIONS]`

Ref : https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/create/